# Error in betweenness() function igraph Social Network Analysis R

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

I'm following a tutorial on DataCamp for Network Analysis on Social Media Data.  I recently tried to calculate the betweenness scores of the network and I'm getting the following error:

## Calculate the betweenness scores of the network

```
  betwn_nw <- betweenness(nw_rtweet, directed= TRUE)
```

Error in betweenness(nw_rtweet, directed = TRUE) :
unused argument (directed = TRUE)

When I delete the (directed = TRUE), I get the following error:

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
as.edgelist.sna input must be an adjacency matrix/array, edgelist matrix, network, or sparse matrix, or list thereof.

I'm wondering how I can fix this error?  Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I’m guessing you’ve got both igraph and sna packages loaded. either use igraph::betweenness() or detach sna